# How do I get the previous value from a dropdown in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Cell `D10` is a dropdown containing all months. Let's say I change the value from `JAN` to `MAY`, then I want the previous value in cell `D12` i.e. `JAN`.

Another example, say now I change the dropdown value to `MAR` then in cell `D12` I want the previous value i.e. `MAY`

How can I get this?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should **avoid** writing your entire question in **ALL CAPS** - this is generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, it's rude and offensive, and dramatically lowers your chances of folks taking their time to read your question and provide an answer. Don't do it - just don't .

Comment: Title's still in ALL CAPS ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like so:

```
Private vPreviousValue As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("l1")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> vPreviousValue Then
        Range("K1").Value = vPreviousValue
    End If
End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Not Intersect(Target, Range("l1")) Is Nothing Then
    vPreviousValue = Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `Target.Cells.Count` with `Target.Cells.CountLarge` or selecting all cells in the entire worksheet will throw an overflow error (runtime error 6). In recent Excel versions there are more cells than fit into a `Long` (`.Count`) therefore `.CountLarge` is of type `LongLong`.